# java : when can a rollback fail in jpa?

Tags: java, jpa, rollback

I'm using JPA and I begin a transaction before a function is called which will in turn store some data into the database. The transaction is then ended after the function call is executed. But I also use entityManager.flush() and entityManager.clear() guessing that memory will be freed on using clear(). before ending the transaction. Please do correct me. When I executed the program, it failed to roll back.

I also tried removing the flush() and clear(), still I'm not able to roll back. When can a roll back fail in my scenario when I'm using clear and flush?

Comment: Are all the queries in a single `@Transactional` service, or in many? If they are in many, then they each have their own transaction. Could you show us some code for us to help you?

Comment: Code is pretty huge and I'm not using annotations

Comment: Is your application running in a j2ee server?? Are you using container transactions??

Comment: Yes, It's running on glassfish server.

Comment: You said that you are not using annotations... this means that your entitymanager is an application entity manager, i.e., you do something like `EntityManger em = EntityManagerProvider.createEntityManager()`?

Comment: Yes, I'm using that.

Answer (score 2):

> I also use entityManager.flush() and entityManager.clear() guessing
>   that memory will be freed on using clear().

Well you should stop guessing and start reading some documentation.

`EntityManager` flushes on `tx.commit()` by itself, and entity manager is cleared when it is closed. 
If you are using container manager transactions, you should rather not worry about flushing and clearing entity managers. If you are using JavaSE then your normal workflow with DB should look like this:

1. Create new entity manager
2. Start transaction
3. Do your job - delete/update/insert whatever
4. Commit transaction / Rollback if needed
5. Close entity manager

Normally this would be closed in small `try-catch-finally` block

`EntityManager` is lightweight and short living component. You should create one just when you need it, and close it right after you use it. 
What is supposed to be a singleton instance, and created (most cases) only once is `EntityManagerFactory`

Comment: If I removed clear, I was getting out of memory error, is it a bad practice to use it explicitly?

Comment: @AravindS Your problem is that you are not closing entity manager

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. Ya I tried it, it seemed to work on one scenario. But in my case I'm beginning and committing the transaction twice here and it will be working inside a thread on a loop. Since it is a loop I can't be working on a closed entity manager right?

Comment: @AravindS Hard to say without code. Normaly you would loop over points 1-5